# How do you perform a deep copy of a ternary tree in Go?

Tags: go, deep-copy, ternary-tree

I'm attempting to perform a deep copy of the following struct:

```
// Ternary Tree
type Tree struct {
    Left  *Tree
    Mid *Tree
    Right *Tree
    Value interface{}
    Parent *Tree
    Orientation string
    IsTerminal bool
    Type string
}
```

The following is my sorry attempt. It looks like I'm creating a new tree at the root but it's children are still pointing to the same address in memory.

```
func (tree *Tree) CopyTree() *Tree {
    if (tree == nil) {
        return nil
    } else {
        copiedTree := &Tree {
            tree.Left.CopyTree(),
            tree.Mid.CopyTree(),
            tree.Right.CopyTree(),
            tree.Value,
            tree.Parent.CopyTree(),
            tree.Orientation,
            tree.IsTerminal,
            tree.Type}
        return copiedTree
    }
}
```

Are there any useful constructs in go that assist with deep copying a struct? If not, how would I perform this deep copy myself? Note, the "[deepcopy](http://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/rog-go/exp/deepcopy)" package no longer works as it uses a few functions that were deprecated with the release of Go 1

Comment: There is nothing built in. There are, however, [packages such as DeepCopy that can do it for you](http://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/rog-go/exp/deepcopy) (keeping in mind the "experimental" status)

Comment: @SimonWhitehead I gave that package a try. Unfortunately, it uses a bunch of functions that were deprecated with the release of Go 1

Comment: Apologies .. I did not realise (I must have used it prior to Go 1).

Comment: Are you sure the code you give demonstrates the behavior you describe? There appears to be an infinite cycle where parent copies child copies parent. Also, you're not copying Value: is that intended?

Comment: @Anonymous I'm not sure! And, no that is not intended.

Comment: @Anonymous You were on point. I should have been assigning the copiedTree to the parent of of the Left, Right, and Mid children. I'll provide the correct code in an answer. Thanks for the direction.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was close. I should have assigned the copiedTree to the parent property.

```
func (tree *Tree) CopyTree() *Tree {
    if (tree == nil) {
        return nil
    } else {
        copiedTree := &Tree {
            tree.Left.CopyTree(),
            tree.Mid.CopyTree(),
            tree.Right.CopyTree(),
            tree.Value,
            nil,
            tree.Orientation,
            tree.IsTerminal,
            tree.Type,
        }

        if copiedTree.Left != nil {
            copiedTree.Left.Parent = copiedTree
        }
        if copiedTree.Right != nil {
            copiedTree.Right.Parent = copiedTree
        }
        if copiedTree.Mid != nil {
            copiedTree.Mid.Parent = copiedTree
        }
        return copiedTree
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can roundtrip it through `encoding/gob`:

```
package main

import (
   "bytes"
   "encoding/gob"
)

func copyStruct(in, out interface{}) {
   buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
   gob.NewEncoder(buf).Encode(in)
   gob.NewDecoder(buf).Decode(out)
}

func main() {
   type date struct { Month, Day int }
   a := date{12, 31}
   var b date
   copyStruct(a, &b)
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/gob

Answer (score -1):

How about json.Marshal and json.Unmarshal. If performance is critical, I perfer to use protobuf.